# sort key value pairs in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below script running on a google sheet to automatically send an email with the sheet info to a specific emails. It is working perfectly but I am trying to optimize it. The problem I am having is every-time the email is sent the order of the text (Key value pairs) is different I am trying to order the key value pair based on the way they are in the email.

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.namedValues;
  var sendFrom = '';
  var ccEmail = '';
  var subject = '';
  var htmlBody = '<ul>';
  for (Key in values) {
    var label = Key;
    var data = values[Key];
    htmlBody += '<li>' + label + ": " + data + '</li>';
  };
  htmlBody += '</ul>';
  MailApp.sendEmail(sendFrom, subject, htmlBody, {
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
    cc: ccEmail,
    name: 'Automated Email',
    noReply: true

  });
}
```

Thank you for help in advance

Comment: can you show log of `values`also can you share form please?

Comment: I guess you mean you are trying to order them based on the way they are in the sheet? You said based on how they are in the email but is that a typo?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access just the values (in correct order) with e.values, then dynamically create the "keys" by accessing the header row from the destination 'Form Responses' sheet:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var values = e.values;
  var vlen = values.length;
//get headers from response sheet (i.e. form questions)
  var keys= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Form Responses 1!A1:1').getValues()[0];
  var i;
  var htmlBody = '<ul>';

  for (i=0;i<vlen;i++) {
    
    var label = keys[i];
    var data = values[i];
    htmlBody += '<li>' + label + ": " + data + '</li>';
    
  };
  
  htmlBody += '</ul>';
/mail part etc.]
```

This way any edits the the questions in the form won't break your code.

Answer (score 0):

A key value pair doesn't maintain order. So, you should create an array of keys to maintain the order instead, then iterate the array to retrieve each item in values.

example

```js
  var orderedKeys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone']
```

Then in your function, instead of iterating on `values`, you iterate on `orderedKeys` instead.

```js
  for (var key of orderedKeys) {
    var data = values[Key];
    htmlBody += '<li>' + key + ": " + data + '</li>';
  }
```